# How can I merge keepass database stored in mercurial repository?

Tags: linux, merge, mercurial, keepass

I use mercurial to store passwords inside a repository. The problem is that mercurial cannot merge keepass databases. How can I handle this?

I run GNU/Linux by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not alone! I had this problem too.

First of all, you need to install KPScript. It's a little bit tedious process on GNU/Linux, which is described here: http://adunumdatum.org/kepass2-kpscript-installation-on-linux.html.
To sum up this article:

1. Download `KPScript.exe`.
2. Find `KeePass.exe` location by viewing content of `/usr/bin/keepass` (for me it was `/usr/lib/keepass/KeePass.exe`).
3. Copy `KPScript.exe` to the same folder:

   ```
   sudo install -D -m644 KPScript.exe "/usr/lib/keepass/KPScript.exe"
   echo -e '#!/bin/sh\n/usr/bin/mono --runtime=v4.0 /usr/lib/keepass/KPScript.exe "$@"' > /tmp/kpscript
   sudo install -D -m755 /tmp/kpscript "/usr/bin/kpscript"
   ```

After installing kpscript you can use it to sync your databases (see http://keepass.info/help/v2_dev/scr_sc_index.html for more details).

Finally you need to add those lines to the `.hgrc`:

```
[merge-patterns]
**.kdbx = keepass

[merge-tools]
keepass.executable = /usr/bin/kpscript
keepass.args = -c:Sync -keyprompt $local -File:$other
```

Now you can merge your keepass databases. Congratulations!